# 2 fgets one after the other, the first gets skipped after the first time

Tags: c

```
printf("Give name: ");
fgets(name, 50, stdin);
printf("Give surname: ");
fgets(surname, 50, stdin);
```

All that is in a loop and beyond the first time, it prints the command to give name then completely skips it and prints the command to give surname. The loop is an endless while (in my code it has an out with break; and it ends after a little while):

```
while (1) {
    printf("Give name : ");
    fgets(name, 50, stdin);
    printf("Give surname: ");
    fgets(surname, 50, stdin);
    printf("Give ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &ID);
}
```

And the `name` and `surname` are arrays. Why is it skipping the names beyond the first?

**Edit:**

You were right. Below I had a `scanf` for their `ID` number and totally forgot to use `getchar` to get rid of the `\n` character. Thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: What are you doing *before* the loop? Are you using e.g. `scanf` to read some other input?

Comment: Most likely, because your actual loop contains more code that you haven't posted here. Please post only code that you have tested.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted does not seem to have major problems, yet there are issues:

- The call to `scanf("%d", &ID);`, for which you do not check for success, leaves a pending linefeed in `stdin`.
- you do not test the return value of `fgets()`.  It returns `NULL` at end of file. You would get an endless loop if you do not break then.
- your C library might not flush the output before read `stdin` in `fgets()`. This could explain the behavior.  Add calls to `fflush(stdout);` to fix this:

  ```
  for (;;) {
      printf("Give name : ");
      fflush(stdout);
      if (!fgets(name, 50, stdin))
          break;
      printf("Give surname: ");
      fflush(stdout);
      if (!fgets(surname, 50, stdin))
          break;
      printf("Give ID: ");
      fflush(stdout);
      if (scanf("%d", &ID) != 1)
          break;
      scanf("%*[^\n]");  /* consume extra characters on line, if any */
      scanf("%*c");      /* consume the linefeed */
  }
  ```